# Ruby, using interpolation in variables' names

Tags: ruby, variables, interpolation

If I have variables as below,

```
i = 1
k1 = 20
```

is there any ways to get values of k1 with the interpolation of i?

Something like,

```
k"#{i}"
=> 20
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible with "eval" but don't do it. It's a bad programming, IMO.

Comment: Why would it be so? I'm new to programming. Please enlighten me.

Comment: My English is not very good but I will try. 1) Eval is unsafe. 2) You really want to use an array. 3) Symbolic references (and it's a really symbolic reference - a variable keeping the name of another variable) is hard to read, maintain, and debug. 4) This violates a lot of principles of programming - namespacing, encapsulation, etc.

Comment: Got ya! Appreciate your comments. I've learned a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether it's a [local variable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variable+Scope) or a [method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html). `send "k#{i}"` should do the trick with methods:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :i, :k1

  def get
    send "k#{i}"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.i = 1
foo.k1 = "one"
foo.get
# => "one"
```

If you really need to, you can access local variables using the current [`Binding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-binding) and [`local_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get):

```
i = 1
k1 = "one"
local_variables
# => [:i, :k1]
binding.local_variable_get("k#{i}")
# => "one"
```

This is pretty awful though. In this instance you'd be better off using a [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html):

```
i = 1
k = {1 => "one"}
k[i]
# => "one"
```

Comment: eval works great for me. I will keep in mind your advice on using Hash.

Comment: column1 column2 column3 ... and you want to call them inside the loop?

Comment: What are you using to access the database? Most will return a row which is an array, hash or object containing the rows. For arrays and hashes you use item-based access like `row[0]` or `row[:column1]` etc. You can do `row[i]` or `row[:"column#{i}"]`, or, better yet, `row.each { |value| ... }` or similar.

Comment: Please don't actually use `eval` unless you absolutely have to, which you likely do not.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, SJ and Andrew. I switched to using row[:"column#{i}"]. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I've replaced the eval with using local_variable_get from the binding. It's a little nicer, but avoiding this use of local variables at all is definitely preferable.